# Is it OK to edit Python questions to make them PEP 8 compliant?

Tags: discussion, edits

I've seen a couple of edits changing the style of the code with an edit summary stating that the code is now [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) compliant. Most of the time it makes the code easier to read but I also see some Meta discussions suggesting that changing the style of someone else's code is not welcomed. Does PEP 8 have a special standing since it is an official guide?

Comment: Can you show us some examples of this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Please don't edit code in questions.

There are several reasons for this. The most important being that you might well edit out the problem.

Beyond that, people have to work with old systems, and *can't* use the latest and greatest versions of compilers, IDEs etc so their question is using the code they have to deal with.

By all means suggest an answer using the latest versions, styles and guidelines but don't expect it to be accepted as there's little chance that it'll help the OP (unless they are able to upgrade).

Comment: Just to add, especially with python, editing code will likely mess up code since it depends on white space and all that stuff.

Comment: @Braiam - Yes, by all means edit **answers** to update and refresh them, but the code in **questions** is a statement of the problem. Updating it **changes the problem**.

Comment: I don't quite understand the argument. I like to edit posts (also code!), if it is not PEP-8 compliant (Python). **I will of course make sure that I do not make any changes to the content**. Most of the time it is just a distance after a comma or between operators. IMO, this helps enormously to see the code better at a glance. In my opinion, code that is not written according to recognized guidelines is sloppy code and I generally don't trust it as much as I do for code respecting coding guidelines. Applying PEP-8 leads simply to better readabilty, **"Readability counts." -- Zen Of Python**

Comment: @colidyre formatting code is a grey area - especially in Python where you can change the behaviour with a misplaced tab, so it *is* better to err on the side of caution and not change it.

Comment: I understand the risks, especially by changing indentation. But I do not agree on things like adding spaces between operators and similar changes that doesn't change any behaviour. If its a grey zone, there must be some acceptable things and some better to avoid in most circumstances. Don't you agree? I mean what could be wrong e. g. on adding a space between operators?

Comment: @colidyre I agree with you in theory, but experience has taught me that having a blanket "ban" is much easier to explain. While you may be conscientious enough to get it right, not everyone is. There's nothing stopping you suggesting such edits but please don't be surprised or upset when your suggestion is rejected.

Comment: @ChrisF agree. It's much more easier to handle that with a strict "don't ever touch code" message. But I'm also not 100% satisfied. ;) As you said, maybe its a good way in the middle just trying to improve code by applying some PEP-8 and hoping that it will be accepted, without being upset if not! :)